# eosio.contract cannot compile with error code 1 of eosio.wasmsdk by Clion

Tags: smart-contract, wasm, eosio-code

We are compile the [eosio.contract v1.2.0](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/tree/v1.2.0) using **Clion** by following that:

> **Dependencies:**
>   [eosio v1.1.2](https://github.com/eosio/eos/tree/v1.1.2)
>   [eosio.wasmsdk v1.1.0](https://github.com/eosio/eosio.wasmsdk/tree/v1.1.0)

```
Cannot get compiler information:
Compiler exited with error code 1: /usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -xc++ -I/include -I/Users/mac/Desktop/b1/smart_contract/eosio.contracts/eosio.msig/include -O3 -I/usr/local/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
eosio-cpp: Unknown command line argument '-xc++'.  Try: '/usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -help'
eosio-cpp: Did you mean '-c'?
eosio-cpp: Unknown command line argument '-fpch-preprocess'.  Try: '/usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -help'
eosio-cpp: Did you mean '-fno-post-pass'?


Compiler exited with error code 1: /usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -xc++ -I/include -I/Users/mac/Desktop/b1/smart_contract/eosio.contracts/eosio.sudo/include -O3 -I/usr/local/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
eosio-cpp: Unknown command line argument '-xc++'.  Try: '/usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -help'
eosio-cpp: Did you mean '-c'?
eosio-cpp: Unknown command line argument '-fpch-preprocess'.  Try: '/usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -help'
eosio-cpp: Did you mean '-fno-post-pass'?


Compiler exited with error code 1: /usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -xc++ -I/include -I/Users/mac/Desktop/b1/smart_contract/eosio.contracts/eosio.system/include -I/Users/mac/Desktop/b1/smart_contract/eosio.contracts/eosio.system/../eosio.token/include -O3 -I/usr/local/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
eosio-cpp: Unknown command line argument '-xc++'.  Try: '/usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -help'
eosio-cpp: Did you mean '-c'?
eosio-cpp: Unknown command line argument '-fpch-preprocess'.  Try: '/usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -help'
eosio-cpp: Did you mean '-fno-post-pass'?


Compiler exited with error code 1: /usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -xc++ -I/include -I/Users/mac/Desktop/b1/smart_contract/eosio.contracts/eosio.token/include -O3 -I/usr/local/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
eosio-cpp: Unknown command line argument '-xc++'.  Try: '/usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -help'
eosio-cpp: Did you mean '-c'?
eosio-cpp: Unknown command line argument '-fpch-preprocess'.  Try: '/usr/local/eosio.wasmsdk/bin/eosio-cpp -help'
eosio-cpp: Did you mean '-fno-post-pass'?
```

The CMake Options that I am using to execute is:

`-G
Ninja
-DLLVM_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@4/4.0.1/lib/cmake
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang
-DWASM_ROOT=/usr/local/wasm
-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl
-DBUILD_MONGO_DB_PLUGIN=true
-DENABLE_COVERAGE_TESTING=false
-DBUILD_DOXYGEN=false`

Comment: What's the exact command you use to invoke cmake?

Comment: Thanks James for reminding, I have added in the question

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two things going on:

1. I've run into problems with Ninja and eosio.wasmsdk.  Give make a shot instead of ninja.
2. Those options look like they're for compiling the compiler, not for compiling a smart contract.  Can you build something like the exchange example (https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.wasmsdk/tree/master/examples/exchange) without those extra cmake options?